# What are the similarities / differences between the terms anode / cathode and oxidizing agent / reducing agent?

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm kind of confused on how to distinguish the terms anode and cathode from oxidizer and reducer or oxidizing agent and reducing agent. Some references prefer to use one over the other in discussions depending on the topic. Are they suppose to mean the same thing in some cases? Like an anode has oxidation taking place so it is an oxidizing agent? The substance used in the anode can be referred to as an anode but it can also be called an oxidizing agent?

I want to be able to know this more clearly and have a distinction of when to use both if I want to use both in the same discussion so that both of them have a specific idea associated with them instead of just allowing interchange between the terms even though in a sense it is also correct.

Comment: Anode or cathode are simply the material or the location where oxidation or reductions in an electrolytic or galvanic cell. It means anode or cathode must be electrical conductors. There is no oxidation or reduction when electricity is not passing through the cell.

Comment: Also the cathode anode can be part of the redox or merely conducting. They refer to the "place" where the process occurs , but that place can also be involved.